# Couldn't render template "ideas/share.tt: file error - site/wrapper: not found"

Tags: perl, catalyst

This is an example in Chapter 8 of The Definitive Guide to Catalyst and the example from the book nor the source code for the example from the Apress site actually work.
I too new to Catalyst to even guess what this is saying as I've tried everything I can think of and nothing works. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
[info] SneakyCat powered by Catalyst 5.80029
You can connect to your server at http://linux-0lwf:3000
[debug] "GET" request for "/" from "127.0.0.2"
[debug] Path is "/"
[debug] Rendering template "ideas/share.tt"
[error] Couldn't render template "ideas/share.tt: file error - site/wrapper: not found"
[error] Caught exception in SneakyCat::Controller::Ideas->share "Can't call method "search" on an undefined value at /home/atomic/SneakyCat/script/../lib/SneakyCat/Controller/Ideas.pm line 48."
[error] Couldn't render template "ideas/share.tt: file error - site/wrapper: not found"
[debug] Response Code: 500; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8; Content-Length: 9615
[info] Request took 0.038715s (25.830/s)
```

Comment: in your view you define WRAPPER => 'site/wrapper' but the file name is most likely something like site/wrapper.tt

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a file `site/wrapper`?  Looks like it couldn't find one where it looked.